# Support for multiple grant_type with Spring security in the same application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Is it readily configurable in Spring Security for an application to make use of 2 different *grant_type*?

Our Java BE app is to be used by 2 different kind of users via an Angular FE app. User type is defined as a request header:

- Employees: Must authenticate with *authorization_code*.
- General users on Internet: They are authenticated via *client_credentials*.

We managed to define this in application.properties:

```
#employee user
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.employee.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.employee.authorization-uri=https://saml.company.com/oauth/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.employee.redirect-uri=https://appDomain.com/appContext/login/oauth2/code/employee
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.employee.token-uri=https://saml.company.com/oauth/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.employee.scope=theScope
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.employee.client-id=CLIENT_ID1
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.employee.client-secret=SECRET

#general user
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.direct.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.direct.token-uri=https://saml.company.com/oauth/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.direct.client-id=CLIENT_ID2
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.direct.client-secret=SECRET
```

The main issue with this is that unathenticated calls for both user types (employees and normal users) are being redirected to the standard Spring /login page, which displays 2 HTML anchor links to the 2 different flows/grant_type.

The behavior required is:

- For Employee user to get directly redirected to *spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.employee.authorization-uri* to introduce his/her credentials in the IDP as per the *authorization_code* flow.
- For general user the BE should handle the *client_credentials* flow since there is no user interaction.

We have tried with Filters to avoid the /login redirect to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: You could write a custom login page instead of the default login page.

Comment: What the spring security version you are using? As I understand it, what that configuration does is, it creates two oauth2 clients in you BE apps client repository so you BE app can have two oauth2 clients to communicate with external oauth2 resource servers. is that what you want here?

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter like below for each different URIs.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class SubscriptionWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.debug("SubscriptionWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure start");
        // Enable CORS and disable CSRF
        http = http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        // Set session management to stateless
        http = http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and();


        // Set unauthorized requests exception handler
        http = http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
                        (request, response, ex) -> {
                            response.sendError(
                                    HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                                    ex.getMessage()
                            );
                        }
                )
                .and();

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/subs**").permitAll()
                .and()  ;

        LOGGER.debug("SubscriptionWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure end");
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().mvcMatchers("/subs**");
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.debug("ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure start");
        http.antMatcher("/management/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/management/monitoringService/taskmanagers").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "OPERATOR")
            .mvcMatchers("/management/sendOperationReport").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "OPERATOR", "CONSUMER")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();

        LOGGER.debug("ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure end");
    }

}

@Order(3)
@Configuration
public static class WPSWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final String issuer;

    public WPSWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(OAuth2ResourceServerProperties resourceServerProps) {
        this.issuer = resourceServerProps.getJwt().getIssuerUri();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.debug("WPSWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure start");
        http.antMatcher("/wps/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/wps/WebProcessingService").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().oauth2ResourceServer()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomOAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .accessDeniedHandler(new CustomOAuth2AccessDeniedHandler())
            .jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());

        LOGGER.debug("WPSWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure end");
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        LOGGER.debug("WPSWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.jwtDecoder start");
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder) JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> validatorWithIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator validator = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(validatorWithIssuer);
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(validator);
        LOGGER.debug("WPSWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.jwtDecoder end");
        return jwtDecoder;
    }

    private JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("authorities");
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("");

        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }
}
```

}